# How to transparent a single wall in xBim

Tags: colors, transparent, ifc, xbim

I have a ifc file with with some walls & furniture.

When i am using the `IfcSurfaceStyleRendering` or `IfcSurfaceStyleShading` I makes all my walls transparent like this.

[image]

All the walls are `IIfcWall` & I have also tried `IIfcStyeItem` from `IIfcWall.Representation` but it is making transparent all the walls at same time.

Whereas I just need a single wall to remain visible like this

[image]

Comment: please don't include images as hypelinks.

Comment: What are you setting the transparency value to? Are you assigning the same IfcStyledItem to all walls?

Comment: its ifc exported from **Revit2018** with **IFC4 Refrence View** setup.it looks like all the walls using same 'ifcStyledItem'
@Loebl

Comment: Well you need separate styles for separate looks. Also you workflow is a bit inclear to me: Are you editing the file in Revit, or are you modifiying the file with xBIM in C#? In the latter case could you post the code you tried to change the style of the wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the reason why all the walls for ifc file became transparent is that all the walls uses the `IfcStyleItem`.in order to make a single wall transparent u just need to create and assign a new style item to that wall.